# getopt not quite working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am not sure why the code below does not work - I get the error

```
NameError: name 'group1' is not defined.
```

The code worked fine before I tried to use getopt..  I am trying to parse the command line input so that eg if I put

```
python -q file1 file2 -r file3 file4
```

the file1 and file2 become the input into my first loop as 'group1'.

```
import sys
import csv
import vcf
import getopt
#set up the args
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'q:r:h', ['query', 'reference', 'help'])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print str(err)
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        print "Usage python -q [query files] -r [reference files]"
        print "-h this help message"
    elif opt in ('-q', '--query'):
        group1 = arg
    elif opt in ('-r', '--reference'):
        group2 = arg
    else:
        print"check your args"

#extract core snps from query file, saving these to the set universal_snps
snps = []
outfile = sys.argv[1]
for variants in group1:

    vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(variants))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `group1 = arg` is never running, so when it later gets to `for variants in group1:`, the variable is not defined.

This is because you are calling the function incorrectly for how you defined your options. When you have the line:

```
 opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'q:r:h', ['query', 'reference', 'help'])
```

There is a requirement that the arguments with flags (i.e. `-q file1` and `-r file3` be specified *before* any other arguments. Therefore, if you were to call the function as:

```
python <scriptName> -q file1 -r file3 file2 file4
```

You would have the intended behaviour. This is because all the parameters without an associated flag appear at the end of the call (and would be retrievable through the `args` parameter